# How can I use CSS editor for ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs

I need to use CSS editor that can check/validate CSS too in ReactJS.

Please suggest any editor or functionality

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/css-validator-loader

Comment: this is validator but required editor also.this will work in website, where user can also edit css.

Answer (score 0):

Just use visual studio code.  And install "prettier code formatter " and "react code snippets" extensions, 
Then create a CSS file and it will work as you want,
Hope it works for you

Comment: Need code editor in react project in website.where i need to write css.

Answer (score 0):

I have found, it will help when changing css as real time.
https://aurelain.github.io/react-style-editor/